# Python - Formatting numeric values into specific column width

Tags: python, formatting

I'm having trouble formatting numeric values into fixed width columns. I would like to generate text columns like this:

```
10    7  9.215600 -1.921500  0.000000 -9.215600 -1.921500  0.000000  0.012810
11    9 -10.66190 -2.066200  0.000000 -10.66190  2.066200  0.000000  0.013770
```

I have tried

```
" {:2d} {:4d} {:9f} {:9f} {:9f} {:9f} {:9f} {:9f} {:9f}".format( ... )
```

Which outputs:

```
10    7  9.215600 -1.921500  0.000000 -9.215600 -1.921500  0.000000  0.012810
11    9 -10.661900 -2.066200  0.000000 -10.661900  2.066200  0.000000  0.013770
```

I have also tried

```
"{:3d}{:5d}{:10f}{:10f}{:10f}{:10f}{:10f}{:10f}{:10f}".format( ... )
```

Which outputs:

```
10    7  9.215600 -1.921500  0.000000 -9.215600 -1.921500  0.000000  0.012810
11    9-10.661900 -2.066200  0.000000-10.661900  2.066200  0.000000  0.013770
```

Anyone know how I can get the results shown at the top? Seems like it should be easy but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You have to consider the length of the  digits

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with how you want the numbers formatted.

You want there to always be a space reserved for the negative sign, even when it is not present. Outside of specific code to check for negative numbers, I am not sure that can be done with string formatting alone.

That said, there are ways to get closer to what you want. Try

```
"{:3d}{:5d}{:-10f}{:-10f}..."
```

where all of your floating widths are negative instead of positive.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, that is not actually what I want. The default behavior for the signs is fine. It seems the issue with what I have tried is that the decimal precision needs to vary.